# Excel function counting days until other cell changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Is there any function count days until other cell changes.

Example
The order has been issued at 22 dec, 2022. It will start to count the days until the other cell has string “approved”.

I tried Today()-22 dec, 2022. But how can I stop this function if the other cell changed to what I demand and I want to hold the number of days.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should add input and expected output. It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
if(a2='approved',"",Today()-a2)
```